# How can I access a POST response globally in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, okhttp

I have a kotlin script that gets a token from a server. It then uses that token to perform another request. But, I can't seem to use the token in the next request because the token has a local scope.

This is my code:

```
class requests{
    private val client = OkHttpClient()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    fun run()  {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val postBody = "encodedinfo".trimMargin()

            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://example.com")
                .post(postBody.toRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN))
                .build()

            client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
                if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

                val token = response.body!!.string()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN = "text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
    }


}
```

With this code I can't use the `token` variable outside of the request code block. This block of code:

```
client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

    val token = response.body!!.string()

}
```

This is the first request that gets the `token` variable and I need the `token` so that I can use it in another function so that I can perform the second request and load the users info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[use](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html)  is a generic stdlib function used on `Closeable`. Here is its signature:

```kotlin
inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R
```

As you can see, it returns whatever value the given lambda returns. This result is the last expression in the lambda block, so you can do this to use `token` outside of the block:

```
val token = client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

    response.body!!.string()
}
```

Comment: Great! This made the variable accessible everywhere in the function! I'm wondering if it's possible to make it accessible everywhere globally as well? I need to pass `token` into another function as a parameter but I can't seem to access `token` outside of the current function.

Comment: @Quessts it's usually a bad idea to make it accessible globally. It's nice to give clear scopes to everything. If you don't want to pass this token as an argument to many functions, you could gather those functions into a class and make the token a property of that class.

Comment: oh, that would work too. Any idea on how I could turn the variable into a property? I'm sorry it's actually my first Kotlin application. I started learning a few days ago  :)

Comment: @Quessts One way to do it would be to separate the "connect" function from the others. You could define `suspend fun OkHttpClient.connect()` which returns a token, and use this token to create an instance of a "session" class to represent your session with whatever API you're working with. This class would be the one having all the other methods that use the token. In order to do all that, I really suggest you don't define a coroutine scope at this level, but rather expose suspend functions. Define the scope in the components with lifecycles (and close the scope when appropriate).